# I have this php/mysql/ajax code and I want to add a fade in effect when the record show up

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I would like to add to this code, a fade in effect... Every time I create a new record, the code shows that to me, but I would like to add a fade in effect to it. thank you.
Here's the code:

```
<?php
include("includes/db.php");
include("includes/time_stamp.php");
?>

<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="wtfdiary.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {
$("#tweet_submit").click(function() 
{
var tweet = $("#tweet").val();
var dataString = 'tweet='+ tweet;
if(tweet=='')
{
alert('Please type your tweet');
}
else
{

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "post_tweet.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html){
$("#tweet").val('');
$("#content").prepend(html);
}
});
}return false;
}); });
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="container">

<div id="sidebar">
<div id='logo'><img src='includes/1.png'></div>
<form action="#" method="POST">
<div><textarea id="tweet" name="tweet" placeholder="Compose new Tweet"></textarea></div>
<input type="submit"  value=" Tweet " class="btn" id="tweet_submit"/> 
</form>
<div id="flash_result"></div>
</div>

<div id="main">
<div id='heading'>Tweets</div>
<div id='content'>
<?php


$sql="select * from tweets order by t_id DESC";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
$time = "$row[2]";
echo "<div class='tweet_box'>";
echo "<div class='tweet_user'><img class='user_img'
     src='http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a422402df9e5dc54fab6e8131dd19fd0?s=50'></div>";
echo "<div class='tweet_body'>";
?>
<div class='tweet_time'><?php time_stamp($time);?></div>
<?php
echo "<div><b><a href='http://twitter.com/wtfdiary'>Abhishek Ahlawat</a></b> <span
     class='uname'>@wtfdiary</span></div>";
echo "<div class='tweet_text'>$row[1]</div>";
echo "</div></div>";
}

?>
</div>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to add some fade in effect when the  appears

thank you very much , you guys rock!

Comment: `mysql_query` is officially deprecated in PHP 5.5 and will produce warnings. Please **stop** using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your file "post_tweet.php", add a `style="display:none"` to the element you want to fade in after.
And for the JS, change...

```
$("#content").prepend(html);
```

...to this:

```
$(html).prependTo("#content").fadeIn(500);
```

Comment: I dont get it
perhaps you can help me with this:
http://tuts.wtfdiary.com/2012/07/twitter-style-dynamic-tweet-update.html
this is the post
I would like to make a fade in effect for each record
if I do what you say I think I fade all the records that were alredy on the database ( before I tweet the message)
I hope you can help me; thanks

Comment: You want to add a fadeIn animation to this part of your code: `$("#content").prepend(html);`, dont you?

Comment: to each tweet...
I write "hello" , click tweet, and I want to fade in that tweet

Comment: yes if you follow my instructions it will exactly work like you expect. everything you add with the line I told you to change, will fade in. If you have trouble with following my instructions, I can explain it more detailed to you.

Comment: So, first, in my php output i add display:none, to which element?
then when I have
      $("#content").prepend(html);
I change that to
       $(html).prependTo("#content").fadeIn(500);
and thats it?

Comment: I guess that the change would be in the post_tweet.php file...
what do you think? : )

Comment: I dont have any javascript script on the post_tweet.php
what should I do?
the code is in here

http://tuts.wtfdiary.com/2012/07/twitter-style-dynamic-tweet-update.html

Comment: The change of the javascript code is in the code you posted. in the ajax call.

Comment: can't you download the file from that link and fix it? or is it too much to ask?
thanks a lot

Comment: yes, and it worked. I uploaded the code to pastebin.
[index.php](http://pastebin.com/wxKddws3) and [post_tweet.php](http://pastebin.com/h22qCFPj)

Comment: I love you man! I really do! Thanks a lot, when I became a successfull person I will reward you! how can I give you points or smth?

Comment: pleasure. you can upvote my answer and mark it as best answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way to do it.

Make your "query" on another page like : update.php

Then on the page where you are going to include this "Tweet" effect :

**css**

```
#load_tweets
{
background-color:#ffffcc;
height: 360px;
overflow:auto;
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

**jquery call and jquery code ( in head )**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function()
{
$('#load_tweets').fadeOut('slow').load('update.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 7000);
</script>
```

Then put this where you want to show your effect on the page:

```
<div id="load_tweets"> </div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I put that piece of code on the bottom of my code, and It doesnt do anything, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This was just an example of how you would integrate, using jquery fade function!

Comment: but what you wrote makes the record to fade in?

Comment: all the code I put in this question is downloaded by this link http://tuts.wtfdiary.com/2012/07/twitter-style-dynamic-tweet-update.html
In this code, you can tweet, and it goes into a table in a database, and you can see the tweet, but I would like to add a fade in effect to each tweet I tweet